# Is there a way to make an indeterminate checkbutton with PyGtk?

Tags: checkbox, gtk3, pygtk

I am designing a GUI where I have a list of checkable items that also has a sublist of checkable items. I want to graphically represent in the parent checkbox if only some of the child items are checked. I have been searching Google for hours with this and the only documents explain how to style a possible button. Is there a way in Gtk to do this cleanly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Checkbutton`'s parent `ToggleButton` has [inconsistent](http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/index.html#Gtk-3.0/classes/ToggleButton.html#Gtk.ToggleButton.props.inconsistent) property, which is what you are looking for [(screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uung0.png)